# Unrecognized selector sent to instance with TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm very new to Obj-c and I'm now creating a tableview to show what I have parsed from Json. Here's the code:

```
#import "ClasstableViewController.h"
@interface ClasstableViewController ()
@end
@implementation ClasstableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"JSONRead";
    NSString *testUrl = @"example.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:testUrl];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                             timeoutInterval:10];

    NSData *JSONData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSArray *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    self.data = jsonResult;
    NSMutableArray *_names = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (id item in jsonResult)
        [_names addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item[@"Mon"]]];

    self.names = _names;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.names count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.names[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

and I have change my tableview to the correct class in the identity inspector to ClasstableViewController, I see others have resolve their issues with this solution.

but I'm still getting this:

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd8835691c0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd8835691c0'
```

anyone have any idea why?

Comment: In which line, please?

Comment: Try to alloc&init ur NSMutableArray like NSMutableArray *_names=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: @ThomasKilian I think is this line:   ` for (id item in jsonResult)
        [_names addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item[@"Mon"]]];
    self.names = _names;
       }`   I added some breakpoints and when comes to this it crashed

Comment: @D4S sorry, that doesn't work...Still have this problem

Comment: As a side note: `[_names addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item[@"Mon"]]];` is nonsense. Use `[_names addObject:item[@"Mon"]];`  and check with a `NSLog` which data type `item` is. It's probably NSString, not NSArray.

Comment: @ThomasKilian > I think you wanna say NSDictionary, not NSArray

Comment: @FormigaNinja Sure, sorry.

Comment: Please set the "Correct answer" for @FormigaNinja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your `NSArray *jsonResult` is an array of NSStrings, or contain some NSStrings as objects. So when you do

```
for (id item in jsonResult)
    [_names addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item[@"Mon"]]];
```

you are supposing that `item` is a NSDictionary, but it isn't.

Comment: See my comment above regarding the used statement ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (id item in jsonResult)
        [_names addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item[@"Mon"]]];
```

item is `NSString` not `NSDictionary`,use like below

```
 for (id item in jsonResult)
        [_names addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item]];
```

Use [JSONEditor](https://www.jsoneditoronline.org) to check the JSON.

Comment: You wrote exactly the same as me. Was it necessary?

Comment: its not exactly same. Please check properly. There is no wrong in providing answers